# C++ - method implementation depends on member reference variables being set or not

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, member

Let's say the semantics I would like to have is

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(A &x);
    Foo(A &x, A &y);
    void method();
private:
    A &x, &y;
};
Foo::Foo(A &x) : x(x) {}
Foo::Foo(A &x, A &y) : x(x), y(y) {}
void Foo::method() {
    if (first_constructor_used) {

    } else {

    }
}
```

Now obviously I can't check the member variables `x` and `y` for being NULL. Adding something like a check `int` variable to see which constructor was run seems clunky and not extendable. Does anyone have any suggestions for the semantics which should be used here?

Comment: Can't you use pointers instead?

Comment: Prefer not having to change all the places in my code, also, I read somewhere that references should be used in interfaces as part of making it attractive.

Comment: how will you create object if object creation requires already existing object...

Comment: You can't *not* set a reference - you'll need pointers if you need "optional" members.

Comment: @bombax: dangling references make grownup guys cry.  you're trying to turn something that's only possible through a combination of weak spots in the language into a feature of your interface.  don't go there.  you can't have a member reference unset anyway, and it's an open question (for some) whether the constructor(s) should be part of the client-facing class interface.  add a pair of factory methods taking one or two references, use them to initialize member *pointers*.  then your change of types is enclosed within the class definition and you won't have to "change all the places".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This won't work: `Foo::Foo(A &x) : x(x) {}` will not compile. You can't leave a reference unitialised.

Generally, it's not recommended to have data members of reference type. References cannot be rebound after initialisation, which means the default assignment operators don't work and it's hard to implement your own.

It is of course desirable to use references in interfaces to mean "give me a reference to a valid object, I don't accept null values." But it's generally preferable to store such references as pointers when stored in data members. Therefore, I suggest you implement the class like this:

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(A &x);
    Foo(A &x, A &y);
    void method();
private:
    A *x, *y;
};
Foo::Foo(A &x) : x(&x), y(nullptr) {}
Foo::Foo(A &x, A &y) : x(x), y(y) {}
void Foo::method() {
    if (!y) {

    } else {

    }
}
```

This has the added bonus of the default assignment operators working out of the box again.

Comment: Thanks! This is pretty much what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
Foo::Foo(A &x) : x(x) {}
```

Is not legal C++.  You must initialize all references immediately.  You cannot "forget" or "neglect" to initialize the reference, therefore you need to redesign your class somehow--perhaps by storing a pointer which can be null.